# Release-QuarantineMessage EWS interface equivalent

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there an EWS interface function equivalent to the Exchange Management Shell cmdlet Release-QuarantineMessage?

I would like to remote control the Quarantine via a Java application, using classical WS SOAP requests, if possible. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an equivalent command in EWS.  It appears to be powershell only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the EWS API supports this. Neither does the Graph API it seems. You could only use the cmdlet.